# When is the best time to go shark diving in Cape Town (Gansbaai)

Tags: adventure, diving, africa, south-africa, cape-town

When is the best time to see great white sharks while cage diving at Gansbaai? I'm interested to know when they're most active and when the water has the best visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Shark Diving Unlimited](http://sharkdivingunlimited.com/faq), based in Gansbaai:

**Low season**

> January to March, however shark activity still continues and you can
>   come and see Great White Sharks during this time.

**High season**

> May to October is the best time to see the sharks.

**Winter is better than summer**

> Our water is warmer in winter and the visibility better. Winter is
>   also the time when the sharks hunt around the island for seals.